# Setting up Plunker for Angular

Tags: plunker

Can someone please show me why my Plunker doesn't like me?

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ft1YgUsXCnFxfyr5ob8r

Thanks,

JP

Comment: Notice the warning signs on the left side of the editor for app.js; you have some syntax errors in the $scope.feeds data.  This version works: http://plnkr.co/edit/anGiuI3bS8ErZRvuuPpw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems with your data.

This should be working:
http://plnkr.co/edit/buQHJL2QAn6iQcjrKjdX?p=preview